# Lumen request valiadation for post call with ‘Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Tags: php, validation, lumen

I want to use Lumen validation with data sent using `‘Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`.

```
    var_dump($_REQUEST);exit;
    /**
    * Validating the data from the request.
    */
    $userData = $this->validate($request, [
        'userid' => 'required|exists:users,userid',
    ]);
```

The var_dump shows the response below in chrome network:

```
array(1) {
  ["------WebKitFormBoundaryzFladaGHfQymC6Ux
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name"]=>
  string(68) ""userid"

RayDonovan
------WebKitFormBoundaryzFladaGHfQymC6Ux--
"
}
```

After removing `var_dump($_REQUEST); exit;` it show below response:

```
{"userid":["The userid field is required."]}
```

I want to know the **Lumen way** to **validate data** sent with content type **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**.

Comment: I think you need this : https://medium.com/@paulredmond/how-to-submit-json-post-requests-to-lumen-666257fe8280